# Update available via software updater but not apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Software Updater reports that I should upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10. However when I run "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" I get "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded"

hostnamectl does show that it is 19.04

I know similar questions have been asked before but the proposed solution is usually to use dist-upgrade vs update. I'm already using dist-upgrade so I curious of any other possible reasons.

Comment: You have to do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use dist-upgrade to migrate to a newer release of Debian to Ubuntu, you must edit your sources first. Otherwise, apt won't know about the new release's sources.

In Ubuntu, however, the recommended way to doing a release-upgrade is the `do-release-upgrade` command. This will edit your sources for you, and do the dist-upgrade for you.